# How to navigate to a page in NavigationView in WinUI3 using C++

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, desktop-application, winui-3, c++-winrt

I am working on very simple demo of NavigationView in WinUI3 using C++.[image]

It is very unfortunate that there is no material or tutorial available for this.

```
<Window
    x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                    IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="False"
                    IsTabStop="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="Left">

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Page2" Content="Tab1" Tag="Tab1" IsSelected="True"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Page2" Content="Tab2" Tag="Tab2"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Padding="12,0,12,24" IsTabStop="True"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </NavigationView>
</Window>
```

How to navigate to a Page on NavigationView using C++?

```
ContentFrame().Navigate(**WHAT CODE GOES HERE**);
```

I already know how to do it using C#. and I am not using UWP with c++/winrt.

I need solution for WinUI3 using c++

Comment: You'll need to get the [`xaml_typename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/xaml-typename).

Comment: @IInspectable it does not work with winui3. it only works with UWP winrt/c++. Please share an example if any. I do not have that much grip in c++ so I might be wroing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the application model. `xaml_typename` works whether you are using the UWP or not. The documentation comes with an example.

Comment: @GaurangDave Can you show what you tried and in what way it failed, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the C++/WinRT sample code in the [docs for `NavigationView` on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview#navigation) (you can search for `void MainPage::NavView_Navigate` inside the page to quickly find it).

Here is a summary:

```cpp
Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName pageTypeName =
  winrt::xaml_typename<NavigationViewCppWinRT::SettingsPage>();

ContentFrame().Navigate(pageTypeName, nullptr, transitionInfo);

// transitionInfo is passed to your event handler
// if you do this without a transition info, simply
// omit the last argument.
```